# How to use computational geometry techniques to deal with inaccurate map coordinates

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-hull, voronoi, delaunay

I am trying to build route optimization software and I am using openstreetmaps for the interface. I have an implementation of the savings algorithm on the backend that helps determine the optimal route for making a series of deliveries.

The problem I am having is that some of the coordinates being returned for places clicked on the map are wrong. Suppose I have to make a delivery at 2 different places. The coordinates of those 2 places plus where I start from and return to when I am done should form a triangle. Some times the coordinates returned can be so wrong that the triangle inequality theorem is violated.

I have been reading Skiena's Algorithm design manual and was wondering, given a wrong pair of coordinates can any of the techniques discussed (convex hulls, Voronoi diagrams, Delaunay triangulation etc) be used to determine what is the most likely correct coordinates such that the triangle inequality theorem is not violated?

Thank you

Comment: I do not see how the triangle inequality could possibly be wrong in the Euclidean plane. Please be more precise.

Comment: Thanks S. Huber. Comp. Geo is alien to me, so bear with me. The theorem states that the sum of any 2 sides should be greater than the 3rd side. Sometimes when I select 3 spots on the map and feed them to google distance matrix api, I perform a calculation on them where I subtract one distance from the sum of the other two. I get a -ve result sometimes which shouldn't be. This seems to stem from the fact that some of the coords returned are wrong. I am working with openstreetmaps data for Kenya and I can clearly see that some of them are wrong.

Comment: Some more easterly points have a smaller longitude than some points that are to their west. That is clearly wrong. I think that is what is causing the triangle inequality theorem to violated. What I get back suggests either an incomplete triangle or a triangle with an extended side like a triangular flag on its mast.

Comment: I still cannot follow because I am missing details. Can you give a concrete example where the triangle inequality is violated?

Comment: Aren't you crossing Greenwich meridian ?

Comment: Merci mon ami, no I am not. The 2 countries I am working with, Kenya and Nigeria (currently working on Kenya) completely lie to east of the Greenwich meridian, more so Kenya, which is in East Africa, than Nigeria, which is in West Africa.

Comment: Thanks S.Huber. Really don't know how else to communicate. I wish I could upload a screenshot I have but I see no upload link. If you would be so kind to provide an email address, I would gladly forward you a mail I sent to my partner in Kenya (I am in Nigeria) with a screen-shot of my map interface explaining the problems with some of the coordinates that can readily be seen with the naked eye. (I could forward to you Yves, if you wouldn't mind)

Comment: Also, my back-end algorithm is a python implementation of the Clarke and Wright savings algorithm that I wrote. I have tested that it works correctly because I took data from a published paper written by some researchers in Bangladesh and fed it to my algorithm and I got the same results they did. Before that I has tested it with solved problems from two different tutorials on the Clarke and Wright algorithm. @SHuber, don't know if you are familiar with this algorithm but if you were to read up on it, you would notice that there is a step in the algorithm where you calculate say S12

Comment: S12 is the savings you can make in terms of cost or distance in making deliveries at locations 1 and 2 from a depot at location 0. That step would be written like this: S12 = D10 + D02 - D12 where Dij is distance between i and j. Dij = Dji. Now in euclidean space, these 3 points should form a triangle and should uphold the triangle inequality theorem, which states that the sum of any two sides should be greater than the 3rd side. That means D10 + D02 - D12 > 0 always, but I am getting situations where D10 + D02 - D12  < 0 when my algorithm is fed coordinates from points clicked on the map.

Comment: In my previous tests where everything worked correctly, my coordinates were coming from a csv file. Now in those cases where I am getting  D10 + D02 - D12 < 0, you would not be able to create a well formed triangle with the coordinates of locations 0,1, and 2. I may have made some errors in describing what the resulting shape would look like, but I am sure you won't get a triangle even though you should get one if all went well and I think the errors are coming from the map data. I am using the Graph hopper distance matrix API to calculate distances from the coordinates.

Comment: I have little or no reason to believe anything is wrong with the API because I have compared it to the output of the Google Maps Distance Matrix API and they are similar. Please forgive me if my response times are slow. I am currently on leave and power is a major challenge. I should be back in the office on Monday and should be able to make more prompt responses between the hours of 8am - 5pm GMT + 1.

Comment: On more reflection on the problem and all the helpful comments and answer you have all given, I think I know what is happening though I am not sure. Although there are some wrong coordinates, I no longer think this is the main problem, because even with wrong coordinates, as @S.Huber seems to be implying, the triangle inequality can't be violated in perfectly euclidean space. I think I forgot that the earth's surface is not perfectly euclidean. I remember the APIs asking whether I wanted to calculate distance via driving, biking or walking routes. I chose driving

Comment: As much as urban planners may try, they will not be able to build straight roads between every pair of 2 locations. I think this is why I sometimes get -ve values when I calculate S12 = D10 + D02 - D12. The shape the 3 pairs of coordinates involved in this step tends towards being a triangle but is not quite a triangle.

Comment: Now I am puzzled. Your post is about inaccurate input, which you believe makes the triangle inequality be violated. But now you say that you operate on the sphere and not the Euclidean plane.

So your original question is resolved, actually?

Comment: Hello @S.Huber. Yes my post was about inaccurate input and that is still there. What I am now saying is largely as a result of your comments it seems there is a problem that hadn't occurred to me as of the time I posted the problem that is probably responsible for the -ve results I get in that step of the Clark and Wright algorithm. I will try another tack, Suppose you were going to make a journey from Salzburg to Graz to Vienna and back to Salzburg. Also, suppose you were going to make this journey by hang glider. Assuming very calm conditions, you could travel in straight lines between

Comment: these cities and a plot of the path of your journey would form a perfect triangle and would uphold all laws/theorems pertaining to triangles. If you were to make the same journey by driving, you are unlikely to be able to travel in straight lines all through because the roads would probably bend, twist and turn at different points to accommodate all sorts of urban development, this more so in Africa where urban planning would almost certainly be not as good as Austria. The plot of this 2nd journey would almost certainly not be a triangle even though a triangle is what it would have been in

Comment: ideal conditions (i:e absolutely nothing in your way as it was when you were hang gliding). The reason I think I had no problems in my tests is because I was calculating distances between points using purely geometric formulae. Now that I am using the likes of the Google and Graph hopper APIs to calculate distances specifically via driving routes, the algorithm is now having to deal with harsh reality and is sometimes failing. That is what I now think is the bigger problem and not the inaccurate input. I may have been using geometric terms wrongly and thus confused you, sorry if that is the

Comment: case. As to whether my problem is now solved, well it looks that way but I am going to have to test first. I  am probably going to have to approximate using "as the crow flies" distances between points for now. The inaccurate input is still a problem so I will look at Efi's suggestions for that. I am back to work and have some pressing issues before I can get back to this. Thanks for the help and I hope I have clarified the confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, (as far as I know) there are 4 approaches to deal with the issue:

1. Controlled perturbation
2. Snap rounding
3. Exact Geometric Computation
4. (EGC) Ad hoc

The first 2 have been partially attempted, but they are far from being practical as an automatic way to address the issue. For example, there were several publications about the snap-rounding approach in 2D, but non in 3D. It may be easy to apply snap rounding, but you must be able to comprehend the resulting topology, and above all, the software must become robust.

Accepting approximately equal floating points values falls under the Ad-hoc category. The resulting software is almost always not completely robust---an input case that breaks robustness is out there waiting to be fed. Moreover, slight changes to the code may break it further and require adjusting those tolerance conditions constantly.

CGAL follows the EGC paradigm. Like any software, CGAL is not bugs free, but the robustness issue is eliminated. You can read more about it in the CGAL website or, e.g., in the book "CGAL Arrangements and Their Applications". While the book is dedicated to specific packages of CGAL, it does touch on the EGC subject; see Section 1.3.2.

Comment: Thanks a lot Efi. I joined the CGAL discussion group shortly b4 posting this and I had noticed your activity there. I will research these topics and try and see what I can make of them. Please is there a python alternative to CGAL? I don't know C/C++ but willing to learn if that is the only way. Cheers!!!

Comment: If the numerical inaccuracy of the computation is an issue then CGAL (well, or core or LEDA) would help. But the claim of the original question is that the input to the algorithm is already problematic. So how would the EGC paradigm help here?

Comment: Before rushing into using the sledgehammers, the OP should understand his problem.

Comment: If the input, for example, consists of 4 points that are not coplanar, and the alg. requires them to be coplanar, then the alg. may fail (regardless of EGC). In this case you need to make sure that the input is correct or change the alg. to coop with such cases. If, however, the input consists of 3 points, they define a plane. While it may not be the plane you think of, it is a valid plane.

Comment: You can obtain Python bindings for CGAL.

Comment: Thanks again @EfiFogel . In a previous comment I mentioned that I was using the Clarke and Wright algorithm and in the critical step where it calculates the savings to be had, it is working with 3 points each time. So I take it that your answer still remains valid taking of course into consideration the caveats you previously mentioned in your answer?

Comment: Again thanks. I had googled and found out about the Python bindings. I am trying to avoid the "2 language problem". I heard that there are python libraries called Shapely and Pyrr that might be of use. I will check them out first but if they don't help, I will work with the bindings. Thanks again you have been of immense help

Comment: What is the reason for decreasing the score of my answer?

Comment: Hello @Efi, sorry I have been busy with other stuff so I am just seeing this. I do not know why the score was decreased either. By the way, I sorted out the incorrect input problem. A line of code with an incorrect operand in a subtraction operation was the problem. Thanks for your answer and further comments. That was an education in itself.